# Canvas MotionEvent, bitmap does not get dragged  as expected

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, motionevent

I am using `MotionEvent` and `Matrix` to drag my bitmap but instead the bitmap gets "translated" to a nearby region (most of the times in the opposite direction of press). I want to be able to drag it using Matrix translations. Here's my code.

```
switch(action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float touchX = event.getX();
            final float  touchY = event.getY();
          //check to see if the user is pressing  at most 80 pixels far from the bitmap 
            if(((Math.abs(touchX - player.prevX)<=80) && ((Math.abs(touchY - player.prevY)<=80)))){
                 //if so then proceed to drag it to a new location
                player.isDraggable = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if(player.isDraggable){
                player.x = event.getX();
                player.y = event.getY();                    
                float dx = player.x - player.prevX, dy = player.y - player.prevY;
                player.matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                player.prevX = player.x;
                player.prevY = player.y;
                player.isDraggable = false; 
        }
            break;
        }
    }
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {       
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(player.bmp, player.matrix, null);
       for(int i=0;i<particles.size();i++){
           particles.get(i).drawShower(canvas);
        }    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `onTouch()` method should return `true` to be able to get
   continuously values from the MotionEvent.
2. You set the `isDraggable` attribute of your player immediately to
   false, when an attempt to drag the image appears. After that, you check each time, if it is true, but it wont be. I don't know, what is the logic behind that, but try something else!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem wasn't the 1 but actually 2. You were right about that. Now I call the `player.isDraggable=false` by a function call from a different class (instead of setting it to false right away) so that now it gets dragged properly